# Spring Boot with Camunda Application

Tags: rest, spring-boot, camunda

I have some problems understanding Spring Boot + Camunda.

Basically I want to have a backend (REST) for my application. For that I have created a Spring Boot Java project. It runs perfectly. Now I want to include Camunda BPM workflow into my application for the processes.

I have added the dependencies to my pom.xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.countandcare</groupId>
    <artifactId>carorderprocess</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>carorderprocess</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from camunda -->
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <camunda.version>7.9.0-ee</camunda.version>
        <camunda.boot.version>3.0.0</camunda.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-ee</artifactId>
            <version>${camunda.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-assert</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.camunda.bpm.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>camunda-bpm-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.132</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Main class is:

```java
    package de.countandcare.carorderprocess;
 
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication
    public class CarorderprocessApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarorderprocessApplication.class, args);
    }

    }
```

And I have a controller:

```java
    package de.countandcare.carorderprocess.controller;
    
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    @RestController
    public class OrderController {
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/")
        public String index() {
            return "index";
        }
    
    }
```

Now I want to reach my application on `localhost:8080/` which should return index.

Now when I run the application I get this error:

```
        objc[39624]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1029c34c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x102a8b4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    
     ____                                 _         ____  ____  __  __
    / ___| __ _ _ __ ___  _   _ _ __   __| | __ _  | __ )|  _ \|  \/  |
    | |   / _` | '_ ` _ \| | | | '_ \ / _` |/ _` | |  _ \| |_) | |\/| |
    | |__| (_| | | | | | | |_| | | | | (_| | (_| | | |_) |  __/| |  | |
    \____/\__,_|_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_| |____/|_|   |_|  |_|
    
      Spring-Boot:  (v2.1.5.RELEASE)
      Camunda BPM: (v7.9.0-ee)
      Camunda BPM Spring Boot Starter: (v3.0.0)
    
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.175  INFO 39624 --- [           main] d.c.c.CarorderprocessApplication         : Starting CarorderprocessApplication on U2007750s-MBP.fritz.box with PID 39624 (/Users/u2007750/CC/Develop/projects/Kfz-Bestellprozess/backend/carorderprocess/target/classes started by u2007750 in /Users/u2007750/CC/Develop/projects/Kfz-Bestellprozess/backend/carorderprocess)
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.177  INFO 39624 --- [           main] d.c.c.CarorderprocessApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.888  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.904  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.904  INFO 39624 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.978  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2019-11-12 21:47:41.979  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 774 ms
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.161  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.219  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [META-INF/resources/index.html]
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.228  INFO 39624 --- [           main] org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot              : STARTER-SB040 Setting up jobExecutor with corePoolSize=3, maxPoolSize:10
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.229  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'camundaTaskExecutor'
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.242  WARN 39624 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineConfigurationImpl' defined in class path resource [org/camunda/bpm/spring/boot/starter/CamundaBpmConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'processEngineConfigurationImpl' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'camundaDatasourceConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.242  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'camundaTaskExecutor'
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.242  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.244  INFO 39624 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.248 ERROR 39624 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Failed to destroy the filter named [Engines Filter] of type [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyProcessEnginesFilter]
    
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.destroy(LazyDelegateFilter.java:49) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4562) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5380) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:475) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:994) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:465) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:320) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at de.countandcare.carorderprocess.CarorderprocessApplication.main(CarorderprocessApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.249 ERROR 39624 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Failed to destroy the filter named [Security Filter] of type [org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazySecurityFilter]
    
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.webapp.filter.LazyDelegateFilter.destroy(LazyDelegateFilter.java:49) ~[camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp-core-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.release(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:301) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStop(StandardContext.java:4562) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5380) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.stopInternal(ContainerBase.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal(StandardService.java:475) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stopInternal(StandardServer.java:994) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.stop(Tomcat.java:465) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.19.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stopTomcat(TomcatWebServer.java:250) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.stop(TomcatWebServer.java:306) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.stopAndReleaseWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:320) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
        at de.countandcare.carorderprocess.CarorderprocessApplication.main(CarorderprocessApplication.java:14) [classes/:na]
    
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.257  INFO 39624 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
    
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2019-11-12 21:47:42.316 ERROR 39624 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
    
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************
    
    Description:
    
    Field transactionManager in org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.configuration.impl.DefaultDatasourceConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' that could not be found.
    
    The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
        - Bean method 'transactionManager' in 'DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.DataSourceTransactionManagerConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans
    
    
    Action:
    
    Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' in your configuration.
    
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is the error coming? All my maven dependencies are correctly resolved. Also how can I access the Camuna webapp, which shows me my processes/tasks etc...

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter/example-simple

Comment: I have seen that already. There they also dont have a REST Api. I i need an example where you have a normal REST Api, which then in turn triggers the camunda workflow.

Comment: I would suggest to get started with Documentation for Camunda, i worked very long back, but you need to setup camunda so that you can view the Camunda Dashboard. Camunda app connects to DB to store the process state, you application should also be connecting to same DB. In this way you will be able to See the Process running on Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your stack trace i think you missed the database configuration for your H2 dB.

Please add these props in your `application.propeties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Still same error. Also it says `Cannot resolve class or package 'h2'` in second line

Comment: @farahm can you paste the complete stack trace??

Comment: @farahm there are multiple bean found in your project for data source properties. Make any one of the bean and make it as a primary bean.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: After I have added the dependency `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>`, I get: `Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver`

Comment: Ok got it, I had to change scope to runtime fpr h2 dependency: `<scope>runtime</scope>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version matrix: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.11/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/version-compatibility/

You want to use spring boot 2.1.x with the starter 3.0.0 ... but 2.1.x support was only introduced with 3.2 
Rule of thumb: use the latest versions ... especially when you start a fresh project. There is a lot going on in spring boot and some hard to maintain (jersey/mybatis) stuff in camunda ... so weird problems may occur when you mix versions.